# Akka: how to get the results?

Tags: scala, akka

Consider the following Scala code which computes the factorials using Akka. I don't know how to get the output.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, Props}
import scala.concurrent.Await
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class GetResult() 

class FactorialCalculator extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case num: Int => sender ! (num, factor(num))
  }

  private def factor(num: Int) = factorTail(num, 1)

  @tailrec private def factorTail(num: Int, acc: BigInt): BigInt = {
    (num, acc) match {
      case (0, a) => a
      case (n, a) => factorTail(n - 1, n * a)
    }
  }
}

class FactorialCollector(factorials: List[Int]) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  var list: List[BigInt] = Nil
  var size = factorials.size

  for (num <- factorials) {
    context.actorOf(Props(new FactorialCalculator)) ! num
  }

  def receive = {
    case (num: Int, fac: BigInt) => {
      log.info(s"factorial for $num is $fac")

      list = fac :: list
      size -= 1

      if (size == 0) {
        log.info(list.toString)
        context.system.shutdown()
      }
    }

    case GetResult => sender ! list
  }
}

class Factorial(factorials: List[Int]) {

  val system = ActorSystem("factorial")

  val collector = system.actorOf(Props(new FactorialCollector(factorials)), "collector")

    implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
    val future = collector ? GetResult
    val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)

    system.awaitTermination()
}


var x = new Factorial(List(50, 18, 32, 28, 22, 42, 55, 48))
```

The results are stored in the variable `list` computed in the class `FactorialCollector`, but `x.result` returns the empty `list`.

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't use form `context.actorOf(Props(new FactorialCalculator))` but:
`context.actorOf(Props[FactorialCalculator])` [source](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/actors.html#creating-actors)

Second you can send messege to FactorialCollector for anwser, for instance:

```
def receive = {
  ....
  case GiveMeResult => sender ! list
  ....
}
```

or instead of giving the list with integers to compute in constructor, you can send it to Collector by ask method. Then you got future with computed result at the end.

Comment: Thank you Mariusz. But I'm a newbie in Scala and after spending a couple of hours to read some documentation I have not been able to get the results. Your answer is less precise than what I read so far and sadly it doesn't help me.

Comment: I have made some progress and accordingly updated my question, but I don't get the result yet.

Comment: You shutdown system when last factorial is computed by actor: `context.system.shutdown()`. Remove this line. Also You no need system.awaitTermination when you `Await` for result. Instead this put `system.shutdown()` in the last line of factorial class.

Comment: I have just done it and that does not work (same result, empty list, and other errors).``

Answer (score 0):

you send GetResult message to FactorialCollector BEFORE collector receive all results from FactorialCalculators

Instead

```
for (num <- factorials) {
    context.actorOf(Props(new FactorialCalculator)) ! num
  }
```

you need

```
val res = Await.result(Future.traverse(factorials)(context.actorOf(Props(new FactorialCalculator)) ? _), timeout)
```

But Await is ugly - do not use this with akka:).

Read about stash/unstashAll and context.become(..)

Comment: I get this error : ` error: Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext, either import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global or use a custom one
`

Comment: Ok it runs by adding `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` before your line, but the program is blocked (it never stops and prints nothing).... I'm afraid I will never understand without a complete code.